# Optimizing a social network website

Tags: c#

I am developing my social network website, and I want to know if it's optimized or not.  I am good at ASP.NET 4 and WebForms, but not MVC or JavaScript.

This code is for "liking" a post.  I did not use any JavaScript to do that.  Is this "like" button optimized or not?  How many online users can my server handle (assume max online user is 500-700)?

```
protected void like_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
        LinkButton like = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)like.NamingContainer;
        int ActivityTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(activity.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["ActivityTypeID"].ToString());
        int SourceID = Convert.ToInt32(activity.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Values["SourceID"].ToString());
        LinkButton unlike = gvrow.FindControl("unlike") as LinkButton;
        Label numberoflike = gvrow.FindControl("numberoflike") as Label;
        like.Visible = false;
        unlike.Visible = true;
        if (ActivityTypeID == 1 || ActivityTypeID == 4)
        {
              //check users liked it before or not ?
              // this code will run a stored procedure 
            if (BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table.GetByIsliked(SourceID, ID, 1) == 0)
            {
              // make an object of like table
                BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table nl = new BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table();
                nl.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
                nl.Statusid = SourceID;
                nl.Statuslikedate = System.DateTime.Now;
                nl.Save();
                  // saves like to database
                numberoflike.Text = BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table.GetByNumberOfLike(SourceID).ToString();
             // update number of like by counting all likes for this post
            }

                     }
        else if (ActivityTypeID == 2 || ActivityTypeID == 5)
        {
            if (BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table.GetByIsliked(SourceID, ID, 2) == 0)
            {
                BusinessLayer.PhotoStsLike_Table nl = new BusinessLayer.PhotoStsLike_Table();
                nl.Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ID"].ToString());
                nl.Photostsid = SourceID;
                nl.Photostslikedate = System.DateTime.Now;
                nl.Save();
                numberoflike.Text = BusinessLayer.PhotoStsLike_Table.GetByNumberOFlike(Convert.ToInt32(SourceID)).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
}
```

For the commenting system and posting system and etc, the code is the same as above.  If all the code will be server-side and does not use any JavaScript, does it cause to have a slow website or not?

"Likes" are store on a database like this:

```
likeID int identity specification true ! identity increment true and 1
PostID int
ID int
Date Datetime
```

I don't use any caching and I want to optimize user experience.

Comment: I really think that if your callback may be a cause for concern on performance that you *might* need to upgrade your server box. :-) But in reality the problem here is not going to be control vs Ajax callback + control.

Comment: @DanPantry i am using an updatePanel ( ajax ) and the whole page will not callback !

Comment: "I don't use any caching and I want to optimize user experience" - caching is a must these days, as users are increasingly impatient with slow websites and so tuning performance by caching will help a lot. I'm also unsure why this question is tagged with JavaScript as there is no JS to review here?

Comment: Since it seems you're concerned with performance, have you actually tried profiling or [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not your primary concern, but a number of issues are jumping at me; I'll leave the performance aspects to other reviewers.

> **Naming**

`like_Click` should be renamed `OnLikeButtonClicked` or something similar, because it's a method, and method names in C# should be `PascalCase` (without underscores).

`int ID` should be renamed `id`, because it's a local variable, and local variables in C# should be `camelCase`.

`LinkButton like` should be renamed `likeButton` to not look like it's an *action* or something.

Notice how the syntax formatting gets confused with `int ActivityTypeID` and `int SourceID`? That's because `PascalCase` is for type and method names; these are local variables.

`Label numberoflike` is *alllowercase* and that's not helping readability. I'd call it something like `likesCountLabel`, indicating it's a control and that it's something about "likes count". Again, `camelCase`.

---

> **Readability**

Naming aside, a number of things could be done to improve readability here.

> ```
> if (ActivityTypeID == 1 || ActivityTypeID == 4)
> ```

These values are known as *magic numbers* - nobody knows what they stand for, *they just work*. Consider defining an `enum ActivityType` instead, and refer to the values by their names.

Remove comments that state the obvious, that essentially rephrase what the code is already saying, and those that can eventually (read: will!) turn into blatant lies:

> ```
> // this code will run a stored procedure
> ```

Really? It's an *implementation detail* of that static/nested class (ew!), that this method doesn't need to care about. Whether it calls a stored procedure, concatenates T-SQL into a string, calls a web service and parses Json or XML to get your results, has no importance whatsoever. This comment is doomed, remove it.

> ```
> // make an object of like table
> ```

Not needed. `var myVariable = new MyType()` already says everything we need to know.

That one is confusing:

> ```
>     nl.Save();
>       // saves like to database
>     numberoflike.Text = BusinessLayer.StatusLike_Table.GetByNumberOfLike(SourceID).ToString();
> ```

Either put comments *above* the line they're commenting, or *at the end of it*... but **not below!** It makes it look like `numberoflike.Text = ...` is going to save something to the database. Yeah, right.

Avoid disemvoweling identifiers. `nl` means sweet nothing to anyone reading this code, and `gvrow` would probably be better off as simply `row` - the fact that it's a *GridView* isn't really important.

---

> **Gotta catch'em all**<sup>tm</sup>

This is called *Pokemon exception handling*:

> ```
> catch (Exception ee)
> {
> }
> ```

Why? Because regardless of what's being thrown, it wil be caught. And then shoved under the carpet without leaving any trace. Not good: you should always catch the most specific exception types, those you can reasonably expect to be thrown, **and properly handle them**. Exceptions you didn't see coming, or that you can't properly handle, should bubble up the stack, get logged, and perhaps crash the application.

OTOH, you're getting a compiler warning, saying `ee` is declared but not used. You can eliminate that warning by going all-out on Pokemon handling:

```
catch (Exception){ }
```

---

The `BusinessLayer` static class smells, but changing it to be a constructor-injected instance would probably require massive structural changes.. I'd approach the refactoring with incremental steps towards [dependency-injection](/questions/tagged/dependency-injection), so as to facilitate unit-testing.

Comment: As a small thing on the Click listener. Windows Forms will generate a method with the name `{ControlId}_{Event}` to handle events if you let it be auto-generated. I'd consider that a valid naming-scheme with best-practice character..

Comment: True. Although nothing forbids hooking up `myControl` to any signature-matching event handler method in the code-behind ;)

Comment: oh thanks for your nice answer , i am going to fix them all :)